# Promise chaining and error handling

Tags: javascript, node.js, error-handling, promise, bluebird

I'm trying to understand chaining and error handing with promises. Here I have some promise chained.

```
return ad_fetcher.getAds(live_rail_url, ad_time, req.sessionID)
        .spread(generator.playlist_manipulate) // returns Promise.resolve([data, anotherData])
        .then(client.incrAsync(config.channel_name + ":ad_hits", "vdvd")) // FOCUS HERE
        .then(function() {
            console.log("AD FETCHED AND PLAYLIST GENERATED.");
            res.send(generator.generate_regular(config.default_bitrate));
            })
        .catch(function(err) {
            console.log('!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!');
            console.log("!!! AD FETCHER - THERE WAS AN ERROR:!!!!!!!!!!!");
            client.sadd(config.channel_name + ":ad_errors", err);
            client.incr(config.channel_name + ":ad_errors:count");
            console.log(err);
            console.log('!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!');
            res.send(generator.generate_regular(config.default_bitrate));
    });
```

Now here at the line `client.incrAsync(config.channel_name + ":ad_hits", "vdvd")` I intendedly write wrong syntax to see if error is caught by `.catch`. But when I run this, I get this:

> Unhandled rejection Error: ERR wrong number of arguments for 'incr'
>   command

But when I change usage of that promise to this:

```
.
.
    .then(function() {
        return client.incrAsync(config.channel_name + ":ad_hits", "vdvd");
    })
.
.
```

Error is caught pretty well. It's not "unhandled" anymore.

I don't understand this behavior. Doesn't `incrAsync` return a promise so it's errors should be caught by the `.catch` at the end of the chain?

Note: I promisified redis client, no doubt with that.

Thanks!

Comment: See here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind. This is a question about functions, not really about promises.

Comment: It's indeed a question about promises @elclanrs. If you'd like to enlighten us about the details, please don't hesitate to add an informative answer.

Comment: Try `.then(client.incrAsync.bind(client, config.channel_name + ":ad_hits", "vdvd"))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you chain promises, you invoke the next function in the chain with the result of the previous function.

However, you're invoking your function that returns a promise directly. So unless **invoking** that function returns a function that returns a Promise, you're not correctly chaining.

So either of these would work:

```
.spread(generator.playlist_manipulate) // returns Promise.resolve([data, anotherData])
.then(client.incrAsync) // this function will receive [data, anotherData]
```

Or, as you used in your question, an anonymous function:

```
.spread(generator.playlist_manipulate) // returns Promise.resolve([data, anotherData])
.then(function() { // this function receives [data, anotherData] but throws it away
    // this Promise is "subsumed" by the Promise chain. The outer Promise BECOMES this Promise
    return client.incrAsync(config.channel_name + ":ad_hits", "vdvd");
})
```

Because otherwise, what you've written is basically this:

```
.then(function)
.then(Promise)
.then(function)
```

But you need to pass functions to `.then`, not Promises, if you want them to be handled by your `.catch` block at the end.

Comment: So when I don't need to use resolving data from previous promise, I **must** use an anonymous function, you say?

Comment: If you're chaining together unrelated functions, you need to wrap them in anonymous functions yes. They're unrelated because they don't operate on the same data.

Comment: To try to make it clearer-- the function that returns a Promise isn't part of the larger chain-- so it needs separate error-handling. But because of the way Promises work, if you return a Promise from a function, that Promise is subsumed into its parent chain-- so now it gets error-handled!

Comment: A last sub-question! Could we run a synchronous function and return just a value inside that anonymous function and use it in latter promise?

Comment: Yep, a function that returns a value is the same as returning an immediately-resolving Promise for that value.